# Use Lagrange multipliers to find extremes of $2x+y$ constrained to an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, lagrange-multiplier

use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum and minimum values of $$ 2x+y $$
on the ellipsoid
$$
x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+z^2/c^2=1
$$

My issue is creating two functions that are suitable to use in a Lagrange multiplier process ie the first seems to be a function of two variables while the second seems to be a function of three.

I am also unsure if what is meant by $2x+y$ is   $2x+y=0$ or $2x+y=z$.

If anyone could clarify I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Your objective function is $f(x,y,z)=2x+y$ (it is a function of three variables). If you understand your problem geometrically, you do not even need Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to graph the problem in 3 dimensions to help with geometric interpretation, now I realise that it would need to be graphed in 4 dimensions (I think?)

Comment: You do not need 4 dimensions. Your problem is about finding the tangent planes to an ellipsoid in 3D, since the level sets of $F$ are planes orthogonal to $(2,1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, because the ellipsoid is a function of three variables, I would interpret the objective function also as a function of three variables:
$$ F(x, y, z) = 2x + y $$
Stated formally, the problem becomes:

> Find the extremal values of the objective $F(x, y, z) = 2x + y$ subject to the constraint $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 = 1$.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to make sense of things in 3 dimensions and I think that was the issue